# Docfx doesn't create html files for my unit tests files

Tags: c#, .net, docfx

I want to create a document for my project, and it works okay but seems it doesn't create the HTML file for my test.*.csproj (unit tests files) and it only has generated the html files of src.

Here is my root project:

- Documentation
- src
- tests

and this is docfx.json

```json
{
  "metadata": [
    {
      "src": [
        {
          "files": [
            "src/**.csproj"
          ],
          "cwd": ".."
        }
      ],
      "dest": "api",
      "disableGitFeatures": false,
      "disableDefaultFilter": false
    },

    {
      "src": [
        {
          "files": [
            "tests/**/*"  
          ],
          "cwd": ".."
        }
      ],
      "dest": "test-api", 
      "disableGitFeatures": false,
      "disableDefaultFilter": false
    }
    
  ],
  "build": {
    "xref": [
      "MY UNIT TEST PATH BUT IT DOESN'T WORK!"
    ],
    "content": [
      {
        "files": [
          "api/**.yml",
          "api/index.md"
        ]
      },
      {
        "files": [
          "test-api/**.yml",  
          "test-api/index.md"
        ]
      },

      {
        "files": [
          "articles/**.md",
          "articles/**/toc.yml",
          "toc.yml",
          "*.md"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "resource": [
      {
        "files": [
          "images/**"
        ]
      },
      {
        "files": [
          "source-api/**",  
          "test-api/**"    
        ]
      }
    ],
    "overwrite": [
      {
        "files": [
          "source-api/**.md",  
          "test-api/**.md"    
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "obj/**",
          "_site/**"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "dest": "_site",
    "globalMetadata": {
      "_enableSearch": "true",
      "_disableContribution": false,
      "_gitContribute": {
        "repo": "MYREPO",
        "branch": "MASTER"
        
      },
      "_gitUrlPattern": "github"
    },
      "newFileRepository": {
        "branch": "MASTER"
      },
    "globalMetadataFiles": [],
    "fileMetadataFiles": [],
    "template": [
      "default"
    ],
    "postProcessors": [],
    "markdownEngineName": "markdig",
    "noLangKeyword": false,
    "keepFileLink": false,
    "cleanupCacheHistory": false,
    "disableGitFeatures": false
  }
}
```

How could I fix it? There is any way? Thanks in advance